# Run batch file from VB.NET as administrator

Tags: vb.net, runas

In my VB-NET application I need to run a batch file as administrator.

So far I use this code but can't remember how to use `runas`:

```
process.start("filelocation.bat")
```

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Try
    Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
    procInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    procInfo.FileName = (FileLocation)
    procInfo.WorkingDirectory = ""
    procInfo.Verb = "runas"
    Process.Start(procInfo)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString())
End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try with this code:

```
Dim proc as ProcessStartInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo()
proc.FileName = "runas"
proc.Arguments = "/env /user:Administrator filelocation.bat"
proc.WorkingDirectory = "your_working_dir"
Process.Start(proc)
```

This code will ask the Administrator password and the start the execution of your batch file

EDIT:
This is an alternative without the cmd window

```
Dim proc as ProcessStartInfo  = new ProcessStartInfo()
proc.FileName = "filelocation.bat"
proc.WorkingDirectory = "your_working_dir"  // <- Obbligatory
      proc.UseShellExecute = False
      proc.Domain = userDomain // Only in AD environments?
      proc.UserName = userName
      proc.Password = securePassword
Process.Start(proc)
```

It's a little more complicated because you need to get the input values (userName, Password, domain) before using this code and the password is a [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) that you need to build in a dedicated way

```
Dim securePassword as New Security.SecureString()
For Each c As Char In userPassword
    securePassword.AppendChar(c)
Next c
```

Comment: Hi, This doesnt quite run as I would like. I need it to run as admin but first as the users permission in the small dialogue box, not through cmd. Thanks

Comment: Updated my answer. This alternative solution requires you get the  inputs in some way from your user