# VB.Net - Elevate Privileges

Tags: vb.net, privileges

How can I elevate my program on demand? (For example when clicking a button).
I don't like to set the privileges in the manifests file, I am talking about 
elevating my VB.Net program at runtime.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I appreciate every helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't elevate your program on demand as such. Your options are:

- Restart your application using the RunAs verb (see [start batch file from within vb.net as admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502696/start-batch-file-from-within-vb-net-as-admin))
- Start your application with the required privileges in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Okay, using the RunAs-Method to elevate it. (This requires a restart tho)

```
Private Sub RestartElevated()
    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    startInfo.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath
    startInfo.Verb = "runas"
    Try
        Dim p As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
    Catch ex As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
        Return
    End Try

    Application.[Exit]()
End Sub
```